# SRCSET loading incorrect size when "sizes" is not specified

Tags: html, css, srcset

As per the docs, when `sizes` is not specified in the image attribute, browser should automatically calculated the required size based on css rendering.

In that case, my image is 300px and the browser should choose 300px image. However, it's taking the 1024px image.

```html
<html>
  <div style="width:300px">
    <img
      width="100%"
      src="https://staging.wpspeedmatters.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/migrating-birds-560x336.jpg"
      class="attachment-csco-medium-alternative size-csco-medium-alternative wp-post-image"
      alt=""
      srcset="
    https://staging.wpspeedmatters.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/migrating-birds-300x200.jpg   300w,
    https://staging.wpspeedmatters.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/migrating-birds-380x253.jpg   380w,
    https://staging.wpspeedmatters.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/migrating-birds-768x512.jpg   768w,
    https://staging.wpspeedmatters.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/migrating-birds-800x533.jpg   800w,
    https://staging.wpspeedmatters.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/migrating-birds-1024x683.jpg 1024w,
    https://staging.wpspeedmatters.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/migrating-birds-1160x773.jpg 1160w.
    https://staging.wpspeedmatters.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/migrating-birds.jpg          1500w,
    "
    />
  </div>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/khsyLxdr/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are incorrectly implementing the syntax. The (Number) w at the end.
Try changing it to 1X, 2X and so on. Also have you tried to specify the desired size on the CSS? Remember, HTML will display the image as-is unless you modify its properties.